# How to disable rotation during zooming in the Google Maps app?

Tags: google-maps

I'm not talking about the feature for navigation where it rotates the map based on the direction you're currently driving. The problem is that when I **zoom in and out** using two fingers it sometimes happens that I **rotate the map accidentally** instead. I know I can press the compass icon to turn it back upright, but I would rather want to block the rotation completely. I've looked through all the settings and didn't find one, is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

If I open the app, and make sure I first make a pinch movement with my fingers, it doesn't rotate the map when I rotate my fingers in the same movement afterwards.
So if you want to only zoom, it is best to first make a little pinch movement, to let the app know you're going to zoom.

If you on the other hand rotate your fingers first, it will start rotating the map.

If you only want to zoom in, you can also use the double tap option. That will not change anything to the rotation. But this is a little more work if you want to zoom in a lot.

Comment: So you're saying you know that what I actually want is impossible?

Comment: Blocking the rotation completely is indeed not possible at the moment.

Comment: @MaxD Do realize that with the double tap method, if you hold the finger down and move up or move down across the screen you can zoom in/out without "twisting". But as "twisting" is a feature of two fingers, I agree on not possible with two fingers.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thanks didn't know that. It's not perfect cause it can only zoom to the current center of the screen but maybe I'll get used to it.